How to filter nodes with names that match a pattern or only nodes connected to such nodes with gvpr/graphviz?
I have a DOT file, say bar.dot. How do I use gvpr to output a graph as described below?

let A be the set of nodes in bar.dot with names that contain foo
the graph should only contain nodes in A or nodes directly connected to at least one node in A

I haven't tried anything yet because I'm not sure how to proceed with this problem. I have access to graphviz if that solves this better.

SO like questions to show some progress.  Do you have experience programming?  Does the gvpr "manual" (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) make any sense?  If yes to both, to start try printing the name of every node that matches "foo"

I ended up using pygraphviz instead: https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz. I'm more familiar with Python and this library is sufficiently documented.
